# Frame breaking only cross-domain but not for iframes from the same origin?

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

This question was previously [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952242/why-do-frame-breakers-work-cross-domain-and-can-you-conditionally-use-frame-brea) correctly, but there did not seem to be a solution posted.

If a site has iframes, and one wants to prevent those from being enclosed in a frame from a different domain, simplistic frame-busting will not be useful:

```
<script>if (top != self) top.location = location</script>
```

However, since cross-frame scripting to other domains should generate exceptions, something like this seems to work well inside the iframe:

```
<script>
try {
  if (window.document.domain != top.document.domain) {   // throws exception
    throw "You naughty puppy!"; // Should not ever get here, right?
  }
}
catch () {
  top.location = "/error/naughtypuppy";
}
</script>
```

The `if` above should be enough on its own to prevent cross-domain framing of iframes.  It should only ever return `false` or throw an exception, so is there anyway the script could reach the `throw` statement in a browser?

Would this be sufficient to prevent framing only from other domains?

```
<script>
try {
  var bogus = top.document.domain;
}
catch () {
  top.location = "/error/naughtypuppy";
}
</script>
```

Edit: A similar solution is hinted at here, but one would not rely on the parent frame to include the frame-busting code. [Detect when iframe is cross-domain, then bust out of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365822/detect-when-iframe-is-cross-domain-then-bust-out-of-it) .  Essentially the same solution as "try to access the other frame and bust if an exception occurs."

Comment: Ah, there is an answer already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365822/detect-when-iframe-is-cross-domain-then-bust-out-of-it

Comment: The answer in my previous comment wouldn't exactly work though.  Malicious code is not going to include `onload="checkForCross()"` when it loads the frame, so it would be better to include the checkForCross function on the child.html page rather than the parent frame.

Comment: I suppose I'll consider my solution the right one, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is vulnerable to a form of attack that leverages the "onbeforeunload" feature. The parent (evil) page sets up a interval handler (which is invulnerable to your code, due to the domain difference) and an "onbeforeunload" handler. The second handler just updates some global variable (also invulnerable) to record the fact that the window is "under attack", and then the interval timer (running fast enough that it should be able to become active before the browser has completed the outer window update to *your* legit URL) pops up and updates `window.location` to point to some attacker-controlled URL that returns a no-op 204 response. The browser forgets about your HTTP request and "updates" the window from that newer transaction instigated by the interval handler instead.

Here's the older SO question: [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

Comment: Ah, so the fix doesn't try to set the location.  Instead one can just open a security alert, which of course the user will ignore.

Comment: But I think the error checking above is correct (`var bogus = top.document.domain;`).  Only the handling is susceptible in the same way as the simplistic solution (OWASP's) is susceptible.

Comment: Yes there's nothing wrong with the code here.  Also it should be noted that the browser behavior that's exploited in that attack might easily be fixed within modern browsers at some point (if not already; I'm having trouble getting Chrome to succumb to that, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right).

Comment: Still, I thank you for pointing out the `onbeforeunload` witchery.

Answer (score 1):

I have a site that still has frames and I can't remove them for now.  This was the best solution I was able to find:

```
<style>html { display:none }</style>
<script>
if (self == top) {
  document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
} else {
  top.location = self.location;
}
</script>
```

From this link: [XFS 101-cross-frame-scripting-explained](http://securestate.blogspot.com/2010/08/xfs-101-cross-frame-scripting-explained.html)

Based on a presentation from: [OWASP_AppSec_Research_2010_Busting_Frame_Busting_by_Rydstedt](http://www.owasp.org/images/0/0e/OWASP_AppSec_Research_2010_Busting_Frame_Busting_by_Rydstedt.pdf)

Here is a more updated OWasp [Clickjacking page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: This is not an answer for the question. He asks how to prevent framing for cross-origin while allowing the same-origin.