# Javascript cross domain problem

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Our website gives a widget to be installed in pages (a piece of Javascript that writes an iframe element and inside it renders things and you see rss, images, and other stuff).

I need, after the user do some stuff, to redirect the page (where the widget is) to another location, but using `top.document.location` is forbidden since the page and the iframe generated by the widget are in different location, and using `window.open` is usually blocked by popup blockers.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.location.href = "url";
```

Answer (score 0):

Although *reading* properties from the `top` window is disallowed, some of them are open to *writing* - and one of these are `location`.

Simply do

```
top.location = "http://foo/bar";
```

and it will redirect just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. [It certainly looks like you're right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952242/), but I can't find any reliable documentation on the write-only properties (e.g. MDC, W3C, Quirksmode, even Wikipedia). Do you have a link to more-or-less official documentation on this?

Comment: @Matt, no this isn't covered by the W3 specs - it's rather an action allowed by the different browser vendors when they implemented Same Origin Policy (which isn't a part of any spec either).
But `location` is the only such property (to allow navigation) (except for the 'bugs' related to frameElement in FF2 and window.opener in IE6-7).